# CSS text block not fitting its parent width on :hover

Tags: html, css

FI've been looking into multiple solutions, as I want to include a text in an image on :hover for my first Tribute Page. Although, this has proved far more difficult than I imagined it to be. I've looked for @keyframes, but got into troubles with it as I couldn't do what I wanted with it. Was fairly close, but not close enough.

In the end, the best solution I found is the one you can currently see on this page : https://codepen.io/shalvus/pen/rNamLWO

My problem can be seen there : https://i.gyazo.com/b1540e9e0902acac2813afcf01d0cfab.mp4

As you can see, it's doing its job, but I can't seem to find a way to make that ugly border disappear. I've been trying so many different things to make it work, but none seem to make that disappear. I'm no expert though, and thought I'd rely on your skills to help me. Here's the CSS that's relevant to the problem :

```css
.relative{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}

.A, .A img{
  width:95%;
  height:auto;
  filter:grayscale(1);
  border:0px solid transparent;
  border-radius:50%;
}

.A{
  overflow:hidden;
}

.C{
  position:absolute;
  width:inherit;
  height:100%;
  top:100%;  
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  transition: all 0.7s;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size:1.6em;
}

.A:hover .C{
  top:70%;
}

.img:hover .A{
  filter:grayscale(0);
}
```

Thank you for any answer !

PS : I'm also trying to make the last part ".img:hover .A{" cancel the grayscale value on hover but it doesn't work either. If anyone has a clue, I'd be glad to hear it, but it's a fairly minor issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing

```
.A, .A img{
  width:95%;
```

with

```
.A {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
.A, .A img{
  width:100%;
```

to see if that's what you desired. The code is pretty self-explained.

```css
html {
  font-size:10px;
}

body {
  margin:0px;
}

main {
  background-color:#EAEAEA; 
}

h1 {
  font-family:'Ubuntu';
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:6em;
}

h2 {
  font-family:'Catamaran', sans-serif;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:2em;
}

#tmain {
  background-color:#0B0B0B;
  padding:1.5em;
  padding-bottom:3em;
  margin:5px;
  text-align:center;
}

.relative{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}

.A {
  margin: 0 5px; /* add this to give a space between the circles */
}
.A, .A img{
  width:100%; /* change from 95% to 100% */
  height:auto;
  filter:grayscale(1);
  border:0px solid transparent;
  border-radius:50%;
}

.A{
  overflow:hidden;
}

.C{
  position:absolute;
  width:inherit;
  height:100%;
  top:100%;  
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  transition: all 0.7s;
  text-align:center;
  color:white;
  font-family:'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  font-size:1.6em;
}

.A:hover .C{
  top:70%;
}

.img:hover .A{
  filter:grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Tribute Page</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato|Montserrat|Ubuntu&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Catamaran:200&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <!-- 
font-family: 'Catamaran', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
-->
</head>

<body>
  <main id=main>
    <div id=tmain>
      <h1>The Art of Doubt</h1>
      <hr width="10%">
      <h2>a lifelong work by Henri Broch, Gérard Majax and other defenders of the Scientific Method</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="relative">
      <div class="A relative">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/MZvLK7Dy/250BROCH.jpg" alt="Henri Broch Portrait">
        <div class="C">Henri Broch</div>
      </div>
      <div class="A relative">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/rF4Y5q7s/250MAJAX.jpg" alt="Gérard Majax Portrait">
        <div class="C">Gérard Majax</div>
      </div>
      <div class="A relative">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/T3XN9ZX9/250-DURAND.jpg" alt="Thomas Durand Portrait">
        <div class="C">Thomas Durand</div>
      </div>
      <div class="A relative">
        <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/BZkV8jYR/250HYG.jpg" alt="Michel Christophe Portrait">
        <div class="C">Michel Christophe</div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </main>
</body>
```